# audio not send react-native-webrtc

Tags: react-native, webrtc

In prepareWebrtc function at the end I have the following code:

```
MediaStreamTrack.getSources(sourceInfos => {
  var isFront = camera_front
  console.log(sourceInfos);
  let videoSourceId;
  for (const i = 0; i < sourceInfos.length; i++) {
    const sourceInfo = sourceInfos[i];
    if(sourceInfo.kind == "video" &&
       sourceInfo.facing == (isFront ? "front" : "back")) {
      videoSourceId = sourceInfo.id;
    }
  }
  console.log("videoSourceId:" + videoSourceId)
  getUserMedia({
    "audio": true,
    "video":false
  }, (stream) => {
    streamsDone(handleId, jsep, media, callbacks, stream)
  },
  // TODO: add error handling
  () => undefined
  );
});
```

When "video" is true for android and when video is`{optional: [{sourceId: videoSourceId}] }` for ios, audio gets transmitted, however, then I have to ask for camera permissions which I don't want to do. When I do "video":false, audio can be received by my app; however, it doesn't get send.

Comment: Did you find the problem?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

First check the permissions in androidmanifest.xml. Below permissions should be there.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MICROPHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

Next check the candidate data you are sending, it should contain 
`"sdpMid": "audio"`

Now if the audio is still not there, it could be because of react-native-webrtc is playing audio on earphone to change it to speaker use  https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-incall-manager

Answer (score 0):

as `@Anupam Chaplot` just said about permissions should be correctly set

After that out of the way now
`react-native-webrtc` supports audio only stream as well.

imagine receiving remote audio stream, no video, just plain audio stream
All you have to do is to make sure your `PeerConnection` status is connected
as what you always do with video stream.
and `react-native-webrtc` will play your audio for you. so you dont have to call things like `RTCView` as you did with video stream.

You can just use PeerConnection and don't set stream's URL to a RTCView